# Not getting output for a simple program, help me

Tags: python, python-3.x

This Program converts the hours, min and seconds to total sec:

```
def total_sec (hours, min, sec):
    total_seconds =  (60 *hours + min)*60 + sec
    return total_seconds
input_hrs = input (" Enter the number of hours:")
input_min = input (" Enter the number of minutes:")
input_sec = input (" Enter the number of seconds:")
print (total_sec (input_hrs, input_min, input_sec))
```

Comment: your inputs are strings, you probably want them to be int if you want to multiply them mathematically

Comment: The description of your question is wrong. Of course you get an output. You just don't get the output you expected.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the input you get from string to numeric

See : [input()](https://devdocs.io/python~3.8/library/functions#input)

if you do :

```py
input_hrs = int(input (" Enter the number of hours:"))
input_min = int(input (" Enter the number of minutes:"))
input_sec = int(input (" Enter the number of seconds:"))
```

you should get a correct return value

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the type of input from strings before you use them in the function

```
def total_sec(hours, mins, sec):
    total_seconds =  (60*hours + mins)*60 + sec
    return total_seconds

input_hrs = int(input(" Enter the number of hours:"))
input_min = int(input(" Enter the number of minutes:"))
input_sec = int(input(" Enter the number of seconds:"))

print(total_sec(input_hrs, input_min, input_sec))
```